# Why LCP gives WRC protocol error in pagespeed insights?

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

In pagespeed insights gives error for lcp like WRS Protocol error: "DOM.resolveNode: No node with given id found"

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjNOG.png)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I've been getting the same thing while using NuxtJs. 

It seems to me that it could be a hydration problem. In NuxtJs "universal" mode, when a page is requested for the first time, it's prerendered on the server and delivered to the browser, but is not yet interactive until the javascript is loaded. When the js finaly loads, each component is replaced by its 'reactive' component in a transparent fashion. That process is called "hydration".

If you ever find the reason, please post the answer here.

Comment: Also, funnily enough, I've found a couple of pages that asked this exact error, but cannot be found anymore on Google Search Console Support... weird.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/search?q=%22DOM.resolveNode%3A+No+node+with+given+id+found%22&from_promoted_search=true

Answer (score 0):

This error of googleChrome-lighthouse.They may have fixed this for next version.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with some internal PageSpeed cache.

You could solve it by adding some salt to the testing url, like `http://yoursite.com/?salt=1`